# Is bounded factor co-NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, factorization, np

Bounded Factor.

> Given number n, decide whether it has any proper factor less than k.

Is this a co-Np problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed a co-NP problem.
In order to see if a problem is in co-NP, you need to see if there is a polynomial verifier that could negate the question.
In this case, we could state the prime factors of n - one could easily check if they are indeed n's prime factors, as well as if one of the factors is smaller than k. If not, then there is no factor less than k!
Doing it this way, we prove that the problem is also in NP, because in the same way, we have a verifier that approves.